# Google app script ERROR "Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)"

Tags: javascript, sql, jdbc, google-apps-script

I know this error has been listed several times. I went through all the previous questions and think my situation is unique.

The error I am getting is this

> Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

It is unique as the script is supposed to be adjusted the insert values based on the number of headers in the sheet.

In the end, no inserts are made to the SQL server.

Sample of the logs

> ```
> [[3333096.0, LOADER, 05:30:22, 08/30/2018 05:30:22, 08/30/2018, ACCOUNT HAS BEEN SENT TO Agency STATSUS CHANGED FROM |originalstatus| TO |teststatus| ASSIGNEDTO CHANGE FROM |originalstatus| TO |testassigned| PORTFOLIO NAME: |PORTFOLIOX|],
> [,  , , , , ],
> [,  , , , , ],
> [,  , , , , ],
> [,  , , , , ],
> [,  , , , , ],
> [,  , , , , ],
> [,  , , , , ],
> [,  , , , , ],
> [,  , , , , ]
> ```

[image: Image of Sheet]

```js
function dboupdate() {
  var data = getData()  
  var headerstring = [1]  
  data = data[0]  
  try {
  
    var start = new Date();
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("X");   
  
    var sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + tablename + headerstring ;
    Logger.log(sql);
    var stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    for (var r in data) {
      Logger.log(data[r]);
      for (var c in data[r]) {
         stmt.setString(parseInt(c) +1 , data[r][c]);
      }
      stmt.addBatch();
    }
    var batch = stmt.executeBatch();
    conn.commit();
    conn.close();

    var end = new date();
 
  } catch (err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(err.message);
    Logger.log(err.message);
  }
}

function getData(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;  
  // (filenumber, collectorname, logtime, logdateandtime, logdate,logmessage) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
  var ss = app.openById('X') ;  
  var importSheet = ss.getSheetByName('DBOlog');  
  var data = importSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var header = data[0];
  var headerstring = header.join(',')

  headerstring = '('+ headerstring + ') VALUES ('

  var questions = Array(header.length +1).join('?').split('')

  headerstring = headerstring + questions.join(',') + ')'
  Logger.log(headerstring)
  Logger.log(data.slice(1))
  return [data.slice(1), headerstring]
}
```

Comment: I did forget to add , it is not inserting into the SQL server.

Comment: Pretty sure the lack of inserts is because of the error. I would advise you to not use `for...in` enumeration on an array, instead using a true for loop or an array function like `Array#map` or `Array#forEach`. Similar for `new Array`. It also looks like you get a lot of fully empty rows in your data - consider `Array#filter`ing those out first.